# ReentrantReadWriteLock released by different thread

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, transactions, locking

I am implementing optimistic transactions (BOCC) on a single server. At commit time the read and write sets are validated against the current database state (transactions are aborted if the state has changed since the read). If the validation is successful all the objects are written to the database.

Validations (plus the database update) on different object sets can be concurrent, but overlapping object sets must be secured using read and write locks.

I use the `ReentrantReadWriteLock` to secure the validation, which works fine. Now I am writing a recovery mechanism that repeats the update process if because of some error (after the validation) not all objects where written to the database.

So the recovery repeats the database writes and then attempts to release the locks (after the recovery was successful). The problem is that I try to release the lock from a different thread (since the recovery is performed by another background service), which throws a `IllegalMonitorStateException`. The comment on the `unlock` method verifies this behavior.

```
    /**
     * Attempts to release this lock.
     *
     * <p>If the current thread is the holder of this lock then
     * the hold count is decremented. If the hold count is now
     * zero then the lock is released.  If the current thread is
     * not the holder of this lock then {@link
     * IllegalMonitorStateException} is thrown.
     *
     * @throws IllegalMonitorStateException if the current thread does not
     * hold this lock
     */
    public void unlock() {
```

Now my question is: Is there a lock in Java that I can use if I need:

- to release locks independent of the thread that has acquired them.
- to have read and write locks (and possibly upgrades from read to write)
- not to wait (block) for locks (I only use `tryLock`)?

Comment: See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140767.html

Comment: The pages contain a lot of basic information on concurrent programming in java. A section on Reader/Writer Locks is included too, but its so generic that is does not help with my use case.

Comment: Non-thread locked locks and reentrency are a contradiction in themselves (you need some other token to decide if it's still the same thread of execution). But if you just need a normal lock that doesn't care about rich thread it was created, that's basically a Semaphore, if you need separate read and write locks you'll have to implement that yourself - non trivial but there's lots of existing implementations to look at.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `StampedLock` does the trick for me and can be unlocked from another thread. I use it as:

```
ReadWriteLock lock = new StampedLock().asReadWriteLock();
```

Answer (score 1):

In general it's a bad idea to release a lock from a different thread to the one that claimed the lock. Doing so opens up all sorts of race conditions and other unexpected behavior. For example what happens if the thread that originally claimed the lock starts making changes to things because it doesn't know the other thread has handled it and released the lock?

Instead send a signal to the original thread to say that it has been handled and let that release the lock.

`tryLock` will indeed let you attempt to get a lock without waiting.

The `ReentrantReadWriteLock` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html seems to do what you need if you just signal across to release the lock.

You either need to do the retries on the original thread or have the original thread wait (holding the locks) until the retries have finished and then release them itself. Only the thread that claimed a lock can release it is pretty much a universal rule of threading so there won't be many alternative options.

Unless you want to implement your own locks of course (for example an AtomicBoolean at it's most fundamental level can be thought of as a write lock, along wth an AtomicInteger for a read lock). That's one big can of worms you're potentially opening though. Getting threading and synchronization right properly is *hard*.

Comment: "In general it's a bad idea to release a lock from a different thread to the one that claimed the lock" - that's overly simplistic. Asynchronous programming is a very useful paradigm and easily causes locks to be passed from one thread to another - with about as much risk as you always have when using locks. The only thing you have to be particularly careful is that you're  working with non reentrant locks.

Answer (score 1):

As @TimB points out, one thread releasing (i.e. breaking) another thread's lock is a dangerous thing to do *in general*.

However, if you wanted to implement a custom lock where this was allowed, you should be able to do that.  If you look at the implementation of `java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock` for example ([here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.java#412)) the `Sync.tryReleaseShared(int)` implements the logic for releasing a lock.  If you examine it, it is actually performing the check that you are talking about, and throwing the exception explicitly in the code.  While I don't imagine that it would be a simple thing to do, it should be possible to 
change that behavior to something that suits your framework.

Do I know of any existing "breakable" lock implementation?  No.  I couldn't find one in GrepCode.

Why?  Possibly because other people are doubtful of the utility (and safety) of lock-breaking.